# Traza de varios errores en cadena en python

Tags: python, timeout

Llevo muy poquito con *Python* y hasta el momento no me había encontrado con un error en cadena, siempre errores puntuales y localizados.

El caso es que no sé cómo tratar esto, desconozco cómo realizar la traza de dónde empieza el error para ver a partir de ahí el motivo por el que se producen el resto de los errores.

Os dejo el error a ver si me podéis dar alguna pistilla:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 167, in _new_conn
    % (self.host, self.timeout),
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xb56581d0>, 'Connection to api.binance.com timed out. (connect timeout=10)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/ping (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xb56581d0>, 'Connection to api.binance.com timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import core, telegram, math, os, binance
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/compartido/python/binance/the2/v2/core.py", line 7, in <module>
    client = Client(api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", api_secret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.ping()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 393, in ping
    return self._get('ping')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 202, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 196, in _request
    self.response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/ping (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xb56581d0>, 'Connection to api.binance.com timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))
```

Lo que yo pienso es algo como esto:

`Socket.timeout` es el primer error, y se produce en *connection.py*, linea 74 etc...

Esto provoca fallo en `urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection` por el mismo error, timeout 10 segs. Esto además arrastra el problema hasta `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443)`, en este caso ya por máximos intentos de conexión superados.

Si estoy en lo cierto... lo que no sabría es cómo evitar que el programa se detenga cuando sucede el timeout. Lo bueno sería que si llega a darse ese timeout, que lo ignore y siga corriendo hasta que se vuelva a evaluar, o si no, que haga un segundo intento de conexión...

### UPDATE 08/12/2020

Añado el fragmento de código que pienso que puede estar generando PARTE del problema

```
def credentials():
    global client
 
    client = Client(api_key = "xxxxxx", api_secret = "yyyyyy")
    
try:
    credentials()
except:
    Pass
```

Si yo estoy equivocada... intenta hacer la función y si no lo logra, sigue "Pass". Este código se volverá a ejecutar en sucesivas iteraciones dentro de un *while* en otra parte del código.

Comment: Si agregas tu código seria mas fácil dar una solución.

Comment: Creo que el código no es necesario en sí mismo, ya que no pregunto por código, sino por entender el error que se muestra y dónde se está originando. Si no puedo entender eso, no podré ponerle solución (que ya investigaré el cómo hacerlo cuando sepa el porqué se origina)

Comment: puede ser que no se este conectando bien el socket al servidor, verifica tus credenciales de acceso. si no es el caso puede ser que este enviando un argumento mal.

Comment: Gracias @tecnobyte, es lo que pienso yo también al ver el último mensaje del primer bloque del traceback, lo que no sé es en qué momento se invoca a esa llamada (obviamente lo hace el propio wrapper de binance). Acabo de revisar todo mi código y absolutamente todas las llamadas a métodos y variables/constantes de la api de binance está dentro de un try-except, por lo que no se me ocurre por donde meterle mano para evitar el socket error